# html5 geolocation and address

Tags: php, mysql, html, geolocation

I use html5 geolocation to get lat and long for my web application. 
My problem is that i need to convert lat, long to the actually address if it´s possible to do that? and after that save the address to a mysql database using php.
Code so far:

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude
                + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function showError(error) {
        switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Google Maps API? You have limited requests per second and per 24 hours, so if it is a very large scaled service you want to offer, you might want to consider something else but with the Reverse Geocoding of the Google Maps API you could solve your problem.

Find it here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding